# Concatenating two int arrays

Tags: java

I am looking to take two `int[] arrays`, and concatenate them into a single one.  I realize that there are quite a few posts already on here, yet all of them are using more advanced scripts (`System.arraycopy`, etc.) that I am not familiar with.  I could easily use them, but I lose understanding for why I am using these methods.

My plan looking forward is to set both my arrays to `Strings` (using the `toString()` method), and then trace them with a `for loop`.  Each time an integer is found, it prints it onto the end of a new String that is originally initialized to "".

Example (line breaks for spacing):

array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

array2 = [5, 6, 7];

array3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; //this is what array should look like.

Can anyone offer me any advice on my proposed method to fulfilling this part of my work?

Comment: Removed `(Student)` from question header/title. It's not needed.

Comment: Why would you use toString()? Do you want to concatenate the two arrays or to print their elements?

Comment: Excuse my poor explanation.  Yes, I would like to print the array after combining them.

Comment: if you don't want to use built in methods `arraycopy` then do it manually. Create a 3rd array with size arr1+arr2 and then loop through both array and store their contents to arr3.

Comment: Ended up using this approach (creating a 3rd array and using loops to fill it in).  Much thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use strings here. Just get a new array like:

```
int[] array3 = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
```

Now you can use `arraycopy` to copy the two arrays or, if you do not like that, just use loops. I guess you already know from elsewhere how to use `arraycopy`. As for loops, you can two loops, one that runs from `0` to `array1.length` and copies `array1` into `array3` and another that runs from `0` to `array2.length` and copies `array2` into `array3` beginning beginning from the index `array1.length` in `array3`.

If you want to subsequently print the arrays, use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use a `String`. You can just allocate a new array the size of the two others combined, and copy all the values into it:

```
int[] array1 = ...;
int[] array2 = ...;
int[] result = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    result[i]  = array1[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; ++i) {
    result[array1.length + i] = array2[i];
}
```

Of course, you could use `System.arrayCopy` to do the copying more efficiently, but the principal still stands.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use built in methods `arraycopy` then do it manually. Create a 3rd array with size `arr1+arr2` and then loop through both array and store their contents to `arr3`. Like

```
int size = arr1.length + arr2.length;
int indexval=0;
int[] arr3 = new int[size];

for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
{
 arr3[i] = arr1[i];
 indexval++;
}

for(int i=0,i<arr2.length;i++)
{
  arr3[indexval] = arr2[i];
  indexval++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayUtils from Apache Commons

```
int [] array1 = {1,2,3, 4};
int [] array2 = {5,6,7};
int [] array3 = ArrayUtils.addAll(array1, array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

using Apache Commons Lang library

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] array2 = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

int[] array3 = ArrayUtils.addAll(array1, array2);
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#addAll(int[], int[])